# Handle Shake Gesture While app is in background in iOS

Tags: ios

I am implementing an security / Help application for iPhone in which I want to add a feature of "Shake To Send Alert". I am looking for a way to handle shake gesture even if app is running in background (Clicked on Physical Home button of iPhone). I googled and searched through web but didn't found any answer. I also saw some posts on StackOverflow with similar needs but are still not solved. Do anyone have any idea of doing that? Right now I am able to handle MotionEven but only when app is in foreground.

Comment: An app can't run in the background unless it has a valid reason to do so. (Look up about the background modes in the documentation or google.) If your app does not have a valid reason to use one of the background modes then it would be rejected from the app store. Even if an app does have a background mode it still does not run continuously all the time unrestricted. So your app is unlikely to be feasible.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. If your app is running in the background, it is very limited to what it can and can't do - something like detecting phone shaking is not something that can be done in the background.